# How come my return statement won't print a string?

Tags: java, return, palindrome

I'm trying to ask the user to input some text and print out whether or not that text is a palindrome, and figured out how to do it without multiple classes but I'm a bit lost on how to do it with multiple given classes (assignment requires it). Also, I'm a high school student in an introductory class so bear with me.

My return statement keeps giving me the error : incompatible types: String cannot be converted to boolean.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Palindromes
{
    /**
     * This program lets the user input some text and
     * prints out whether or not that text is a palindrome.
     */
     
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       // Create user input and let user know whether their word is a palindrome or not! 
        String text="";
        System.out.println("Type in your text:");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        text = input.nextLine();
    
    }
    
    /**
     * This method determines if a String is a palindrome,
     * which means it is the same forwards and backwards.
     * 
     * @param text The text we want to determine if it is a palindrome.
     * @return A boolean of whether or not it was a palindrome.
     */
    public static boolean isPalindrome(String text)
    {
         String newString= "";
         if (newString.equals(text)){
        System.out.println("It's a palindrome!");
    //return true;
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("It's not a palindrome");
    }
    return newString;
    }
    
    /**
     * This method reverses a String.
     * 
     * @param text The string to reverse.
     * @return The new reversed String.
     */
    public static String reverse(String text)
    {
        String newString="";
       for(int i = text.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            String character = text.substring(i, i+1);
            newString += character;
        }
        System.out.println("The original string reversed = " +newString);
    }
        
}
```

Comment: `isPalindrome` shouldn't be doing the printing -- `main` should be, based on the result of `isPalindrome`.

Answer (score 0):

You declare `isPalindrome` with a return type of boolean...you need to set it to String for returning Strings.

```
    public static String isPalindrome(String text)
    {
         String newString= "";
         if (newString.equals(text)){
        System.out.println("It's a palindrome!");
    //return true;
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("It's not a palindrome");
    }
    return newString;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a few bugs. The first, is that you assume methods are *automatically* invoked by being declared. The second, is that your code doesn't return the types you have assigned. Let's start with `reverse`. That method should simply reverse the input `text` (**and** return the reversed text). You could do so in a number of ways. For example,

```
public static String reverse(String text) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
        sb.insert(0, text.charAt(i));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Second, to determine if the `text` is a palindrome you can compare the reversed `text` with the original `text`. Like,

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(String text) {
    String newString = reverse(text);
    return newString.equals(text);
}
```

Then your `main` method uses `isPalindrome` to determine if the input is a palindrome. Like,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Type in your text:");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String text = input.nextLine();
    if (isPalindrome(text)) {
        System.out.println("It's a palindrome!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("It's not a palindrome");
    }
}
```